# Is there a concept close to smart contracts in event sourcing?

Tags: architecture, event-sourcing

I'm working on architecture concepts for a projects in very early stages. I was wondering about a behavior that needs to be implemented and its design implications.
Basically: specific events, if a set of conditions is met (both may change dynamically) should trigger emission of other events.

Schematically, at want to be able, to have in my system some sort of contracts that would do:

```
If received: PaymentSuccessEvent with user_id 123 and amount $12
 then:
   emit PurchaseCompletedEvent
elseif(current date > some dead end):
   emit PurchaseFailedEvent
```

(I know that's very broad, and I suspect I may have missed some existing patterns because I didn't word my searches adequately.)

It seems like the behavior is conceptually close to what smart contracts are meant to achieve.
My question then is, can you think of design patterns, conference or author that would point in that direction ?

**Edit** Thanks to  Rafael Almeida, (search wording was indeed my problem).
Rule Engine design pattern is exactly what I needed. If you stumble upon this post and have interest in design patterns in general, I highly encourage you to dig this subject. (Note: it's not really the conceptual equivalent to Smart Contracts, though it's a good conceptual starting point to implement something in that taste)

Comment: Wouldn't this just be an Event-based system, possibly combined with the "Rule Engine" pattern?

Comment: Rule engine is exactly what I needed. I'll edit my post, thanks :)